# Directory wildcard in path

Tags: cmd, directory, wildcard

It's been ages since I used Windows CMD commands. I want to list the PDF files in a named subdirectory of a list of directories. So I think I need to wildcard the parent directories.

For example:

```
drive:\maindirectory\[wildcard]\subdirectory\*.pdf
```

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry, no wildcards in paths with `dir`. Does `dir /s /b "C:\maindirectory\*.pdf` help? If not, it can be solved with a `for` construct

Answer (score 3):

here is one-liner command, just edit the pattern search and copy paste into cmd.

```
@for /f "delims=" %a in (^
'dir /b /s /ad "maindirectory\w?ldc?rd"^| findstr /c:subdirectory'^
) do @dir /b /a-d "%a\*.pdf"
```

Comment: interesting. `dir` supports wildcards in paths - but only in the very last element.