# dir subtree with regex path string

Tags: cmd

I have file tree like this:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\blabla
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\blabla\something
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources\app.package.unpacked
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources\app.package.unpacked\daemon
```

I've tried command

```
D:\tmp>dir /B/S/AD "%LOCALAPPDATA%\app-package\app*"
```

Expect:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources\app.package.unpacked
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources\app.package.unpacked\daemon
```

Real output:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources\app.package.unpacked
```

Why it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841106/dos-cmd-directory-wildcard-in-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that the wildcard `app*` only matches against items in the given target directory, but actually it matches against the *last* element of a path. That explains why:

```cmd
dir /B/S/AD "%LOCALAPPDATA%\app-package\app*"
```

provides this result:

> ```cmd
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6\resources\app.package.unpacked
> ```

Change `app*` to `app-*` and the output will only be this:

> ```cmd
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\app-package\app-1.1.6
> ```

---

I think what you need is the following:

```cmd
pushd "%LOCALAPPDATA%\app-package" && (for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S "app-*"') do @echo(%~fI& dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "%I" & popd)
```

To better understand what this does, here is a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) version with some explanatory comments:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change into the target directory:
pushd "%LOCALAPPDATA%\app-package" && (
    rem // Loop through matching directories within target directory:
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S "app-*"') do (
        rem // Return matching sub-directory itself:
        echo(%%~fI
        rem // Return contents of matching sub-directory:
        dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "%%I"
    )
    rem // Return from the target directory:
    popd
)
```